# Parsing MS Word file into Excel using C

Tags: c, excel, ms-word

At work, I have been given a large MS Word file with many data entries which are all formatted in the same way:

```
01-FOOBAR RANDOM COMPANY NAME
          PO BOX 2482424
          OKLAHOMA CITY, OK 22498-12937
          USA United States
```

I have been tasked with basically copying and pasting this info into an Excel spreadsheet, but it's looking like there are over 1000 entries which could take days. I have some experience in C, but don't have extensive programming experience, and I can get a basic C dev environment running pretty shortly. Can this be done easily in C? Should I look elsewhere? I really only need to run this program for one file.

Comment: Show some more lines of your word file. And show how it should look in Excel.

Answer (score 0):

Try regular expression like this:

```
^\d{1,4}-(.*\n){4}
```

^: line start
\d: any digit
{1,4}: one to four digits (because you have over 1000 entries)
(.*\n){4}: four lines for the address